# Set a C++ member function to a function from a DLL

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member

I am trying to do something like this:
Create an object and bind its member functions to functions from a DLL. For example,

```
class A {
private:
int a;
public:
void func_a();
};
```

When loading from a DLL I want to create an A object, and set func_a to a function that is loaded from the DLL

```
A aObj;
(aObj.*func_a)() = getAdr(&s, h, "fmiGetTypesPlatform");
```

I do not know the syntax for it, but I mean I want to set the result of

```
getAdr(&s, h, "fmiGetTypesPlatform");
```

to an object's member function

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean 3rd party prebuilt DLL? You can't. Just use class with "one-line" methods.

Comment: If it's _your_ DLL, you may 'export' the whole C++ class.

Comment: It is 3rd party prebuilt DLL

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a function pointer:

```
class A {
private:
    int a;
public:
    void (*func_a)();
};
```

Then, you can set this like any other pointer.

```
A aObj;
aObj.func_a = getAdr(&s, h, "fmiGetTypesPlatform");
```

Note that the referenced function, fmiGetTypesPlatform(), is a regular function. It is not a class method (i.e., no *this*, et al.), and it gets invoked via its function pointer.

```
(*aObj.func_a)();
```

Comment: I first looked for a solution without using a function pointer, but I think there is no other way. Now, If a need function pointers, then I want to design a class B which is derived from class A, and holds the function pointer of func_a. Now, how do I use the A ( the base class pointer) to invoke the B's function pointer which will be connected to the DLL?

Comment: Add a virtual method class A. Implement the virtual method in class B, which will return the pointer. But, looks to me that you don't need a function pointer at all. This is the first time class inheritance is mentioned. Looks to me like virtual methods is all that's needed. The virtual method in class B is your function that you intend to invoke via the pointer. Except that there's no pointer at all. Just a virtual class method.

Answer (score 0):

If you know at compile time which DLL functions you want to use, you can make the class members one-line wrappers and encapsulate any data you need inside the object.

If you want to be able to assign arbitrary functions to class members, function pointers will work, with a little extra setup.  Example code: http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/calldll.html

Note that you can call a function pointer stored as a class member by name as if it were a function, with the usual `object.func()` syntax.  In fact, this is how virtual member functions are implemented, under the hood.

If, however, the calls are not static, you still might want to put a wrapper around them so you can make the data they use private to your class.

Comment: I first looked for a solution without using a function pointer, but I think there is no other way. Now, If a need function pointers, then I want to design a class B which is derived from class A, and holds the function pointer of func_a. Now, how do I use the A ( the base class pointer) to invoke the B's function pointer which will be connected to the DLL?

Comment: Declare the corresponding function in A `virtual`, and possibly set it `= 0`.